# Scrolling Up Programmatically On The PowerShell ISE Console

Tags: scroll, console, powershell-ise

Any help would be appreciated.  I have script that runs and displays a list and ends with a question and prompt in my PowerShell ISE console.  What I would like it to do is not scroll automatically to the question with the prompt, or I would like to automatically scroll to the top of the console window. I have tried derivatives of [System.Console]::SetWindowPosition and $psise.CurrentPowerShellTab.ConsolePane to absolutely no avail.  It appears to me that it CAN'T be done or simply that I am misunderstanding something at a fundamental level and simply can't figure it out.   Does anyone have a suggestion of how this can be done?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest outputting our results in chunks until the results are complete and then display the question. In my sample:

- I created a list of 35 user FirstName fields.
- Displayed 10 results at a time with a read-host of "hit any key to continue"
- After all the 35 results are displayed it asks the user a question.

  ```
    $list = Import-Csv ".\data.csv"

    $startrow = 0

    $counter = 1

    $rows = $list | Measure-Object

    while ($startrow -lt $rows.Count)

    {

    $xs = $list | select-object -skip $startrow -first 10

    foreach ($x in $xs)

        {
            Write-Host $x.FirstName -ForegroundColor Green

        }

    Read-Host "hit any key to continue"
    $startrow += 10
    $counter++
    }

    Read-Host "did you finish reading the output?"
  ```

Hope this helps you out. Feel free to modify it to your specifications.

Comment: Thank you Clint. I will check this out.

Comment: Sure thing. Let me know how it works out.